# Handle http requests for any page by one php file

Tags: .htaccess, http, redirect

I want to handle all requests for `http://www.example.com/any/possible/subpage` in a way that they still appear in the requesting browser under the full URL but will all answered by one single php file `http://www.example.com/any/index.php` (like Zend Framework does). The index.php uses the `/possible/subpage` path to deliver the requested stuff.

How can I do that? Is this a matter of configuring .htacces, only? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the "any" folder, add this to the htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !index\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
```

if you need the "possible/subpage" part to be passed in as a parameter, then the rule line needs to look like:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Great! Works perfectly. I'll use this example to learn more about how the htaccess rules work. Thank you very much. :o)

Comment: Just one problem: get parameters are not passed. Is it possible to handle them as a string and pass them as another "outer" get parameter?

Comment: @Robbit add a `QSA` flag to the square brackets: `[L,QSA]`

Comment: Thanks for this hint. Meanwhile I've already made some further manipulations to the htaccess, and I got the parameters passed with this: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [NC,L]`